# How to hide the "has created a masterpiece" announcement?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Well, the title says it.

I tried to edit the /data/init/announcements.txt:

```
[MASTERPIECE_ARCHITECTURE:A_D:D_D]
[MASTERPIECE_CONSTRUCTION:A_D:D_D]
```

and delete the

```
:A_D:D_D
```

but it didn't work. Should I write something instead?

Comment: Stop cooking masterwork roasts? In all seriousness, if you weren't making masterpiece Architecture or Constructions in the first place, the disabling of those two lines doesn't look like it would do anything to help you out.

Comment: It's because of masterpiece rock mugs. :) These two lines are the closest thing to what I want, I guess. Is disabling the announcement even possible?

Comment: it doesn't seem to be. But if it's rock mugs! Let your master craftsman live out the rest of his days in leisurely non rock-mug-making activities! I assume you're just making rock mugs to get rid of worthless stone?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best solution. Let somebody else do the mugging! :D And, well, the mugs are for the caravans. I don't sell them anything else. :) Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file *needs* something to be in those lines, so deleting them won't work, nor will giving them no flags. Understanding what they mean will help though!

**D_D** means "dwarf mode display". This flag makes the announcement show up in fortress mode, on the screen and in your logs.

**A_D** means "adventure mode display". This flag makes the announcement show up in adventure mode, on the screen and in the adventure log.

So the fix is easy enough: You only care about dwarf mode and you need *something* there, so change the line to:

```
[MASTERPIECE_ARCHITECTURE:A_D]
[MASTERPIECE_CONSTRUCTION:A_D]
```

Now only adventurers will ever be notified that they've created a masterwork rock mug, and your fortressed dwarves can quietly mug in peace.

Comment: Hm, doesn't work... I guess the mug is not really a construction, as Raven Dreamer mentioned above. I guess it hides the construction/architecture ones though, so I'll accept this answer. It's handy to know that there HAS to be something and the MASTERPIECE_ARCHITECTURE] won't do.

Comment: Huh, I guess it's not. In that case, I'm not sure what the distinction is between "architecture" and "constructions". I looked through the file and couldn't find anything about masterwork items apart from those, so I guess the announcements.txt file is incomplete for now. Maybe in a future update more announcements will be moved out of hardcode and into the file.